# User-defined methods and the __func__ attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone explain what the following section on *user-defined functions* in the [Python datamodel reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types) is about?

> When a user-defined method object is created by retrieving another
>   method object from a class or instance, the behaviour is the same as
>   for a function object, except that the `__func__` attribute of the new
>   instance is not the original method object but its `__func__` attribute.

I tried to test this with:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print 'done'
    bar = foo
class B(object): pass

a = A()
b = B()
b.f = a.foo
b.f.__func__  #output:- <function foo at 0x7fe55bed4230>
a.foo.__func__ #output:- <function foo at 0x7fe55bed4230>
```

Both statements are giving me the same output but `b.f.__func__` is not giving me the original
method object. Did I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text describes the binding behaviour; if a method is already bound, but you retrieve it through the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) then a method object will act just like a function object, but the `__func__` attribute is reused rather than have the new method object point to the old.

You trigger the descriptor protocol, by accessing `foo` as an attribute of either the class or the instance:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def foo(self):
...         print 'done'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x1007611d0>>
>>> A.foo
<unbound method A.foo>
>>> A.__dict__['foo']
<function foo at 0x10075cc08>
>>> A.bar = A.foo
>>> A.bar
<unbound method A.foo>
>>> A.__dict__['bar']
<unbound method A.foo>
>>> a.bar
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A object at 0x1007611d0>>
>>> a.bar.__func__
<function foo at 0x10075cc08>
```

In the above session, I used `A.__dict__` to bypass the descriptor protocol. You can see that `A.__dict__['foo']` is a function object, but `A.__dict__['bar']` is an unbound method. Yet when you access either `A.bar` or `a.bar` you get a method object that points to the original function object, not to the method we retrieved from `A.foo`.

So your understanding appears to be correct; `b.f` is the (bound) `a.foo` method, and thus `b.f.__func__` will lead to the same object as `a.foo.__func__`.

Comment: Is this python 2.7? I read on another post that python 3.x will return a function when `A.foo` is called. Am I just mistaken?

Comment: @Dzhao: yes, this is Python 2.7; in Python 3.x `A.foo` returns the function object unchanged.

Comment: what is the 'attribute is reused rather than have the new method object point to the old' mean?

Comment: @henryren: the descriptor protocol calls `__get__` on function or method objects. `function.__get__()` returns a method object whose `__func__` attribute points to the original function. Calling `method.__get__` returns a new method object whose `__func__` attribute also points to the same original function object, not the method object you called `__get__` on. Some people might expect the `__func__` attribute to point to the method object instead, creating a chain.

Comment: This doesn't apply to python 3 where there's no "unbound method" but as of python 3.7 the exact same wording still exists in the documentation. Which makes me wonder - did they forget to delete this passage or did they mean something else entirely? How can you "retrieve another method object from a class or instance" in python 3?

Comment: I can see that method's `__get__` performs rebinding only if `__self__` == NULL but how can you make it NULL in the first place?

Comment: Not that I’m in a position right now to verify what happens; I’m on a mobile device and won’t be able to test until tomorrow at the earliest.

Comment: `PyMethod_New` won't let you create method with NULL `__self__` and any attempt to use one results in `PyErr_BadInternalCall`, in python 2 on the other hand NULL `__self__` meant "unbound method". So I think both documentation and descriptor protocol code are useless leftovers from python 2.

Comment: @panda-34: I've submitted a pull request to [clean out those vestiges](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/12169).